# iterating over structure with perl

Tags: perl

im still beginner with perl , here im trying to loop over `$struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'networkInfo'};` and its dump looks like :

```
$VAR1 = {
            'utcTimeOffsetInfo' => [
                                     {
                                       'utcTimeOffset' => '+0100',
                                       'utcTimeOffsetCode' => 0
                                     }
                                   ],
            'recEntityInfo' => [
                                 {
                                   'recEntityId' => '87.238.128.37',
                                   'recEntityType' => 2,
                                   'recEntityCode' => 0
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'recEntityCode' => 1,
                                   'recEntityType' => 2,
                                   'recEntityId' => '213.233.130.201'
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'recEntityId' => '353876999524',
                                   'recEntityCode' => 1,
                                   'recEntityType' => 1
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'recEntityCode' => 3,
                                   'recEntityType' => 1,
                                   'recEntityId' => '353876999523'
                                 }
                               ]
          };
```

i just want to get the `recEntityCode` where `recEntityType = 2` and store it in veriable `$recEntityCode_2` and same thing for `recEntityType = 1` `$recEntityCode_1` , only one value for each on of them just first catch then break out the loop

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use TAP3::Tap3edit;
use Data::Dumper;



printDir(".");
sub printDir{
opendir(DIR, $_[0]);
my @files;
my @dirs;
 (@files) = readdir(DIR);
 foreach my $file (@files) {
    if (-f $file and substr($file,0,2) eq "CD") {


     my $tap3 = TAP3::Tap3edit->new;

     my $tap_file = $file;
$tap3->decode($tap_file)  or  die $tap3->error; 

my $struct=$tap3->structure;

my $Tracker = $struct->{'transferBatch'};
if (defined $Tracker){



my $rectag = $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'networkInfo'}->{'recEntityInfo'};

$count_1=0;
$count_2=0
foreach my $rectag1( @{$rectag} )
{
    if ($rectag1->{'recEntityType'} && int($rectag1->{'recEntityType'}) == 2){
      $var1_recEntityType = $rectag1->{'recEntityCode'}
      $count_1 = $count_1 + 1;
    }
    if ($rectag1->{'recEntityType'} && int($rectag1->{'recEntityType'}) == 1){
      $var1_recEntityType = $rectag1->{'recEntityCode'}
      $count_2 = $count_2 + 1;
    }
    if ($count_1 = 1 && $count_2 = 1)
    {
    break;
    }
}

print $recEntityCode_2;
print$recEntityCode_1;
$tap3->encode("$tap_file")  or  die $tap3->error; 

}
    }

 } 

 closedir(DIR);
}
```

Comment: There is no `break` statement in Perl. Also you are not showing us the full code, or you don't have `use strict` and `use warnings`. There might be other typos in your code. What is the output you are getting?

Comment: im keep getting errors, no i use strict and warnings dear

Comment: Can you please show the exact `Dumper` call you used?

Comment: Re "*There is no `break` statement in Perl.*", Well, there is, but it's invoked as `last`.

Comment: `$count_1 = 1` is probably supposed to be `$count_1 == 1`, etc

Comment: Re "*im keep getting errors*", What errors? Please add the error messages you get to your question.

Comment: No, the break statement (`last`) does not require `use feature 'switch'` or `use v5.10`

Comment: @simbabque, noone's talking about that but you

Comment: @simbabque, I know. But you incorrectly pointed out what was wrong. There's no need to find an alternative way of achieving what they are trying to do, they just need to use the right spelling.

Comment: @ikegami i have updated my question with full code can you take a look

Comment: ??? I asked for the exact call to `Dumper`?

Comment: sorry brother im still beginner i wish i understand what you want `$t = $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'networkInfo'};` then `print Dumper \$t;` , sorry i did understand well

Comment: You need to tag someone (`@ikegami`) for them to get notified if it's not tehir post to which you are replying.

Comment: `print Dumper \$t;` should have been `print Dumper $t`. That explains the extra `\` in the output (which I removed).

Comment: @ikegami brother do you have any idea about this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096959/decoding-list-of-file-on-conditions?noredirect=1#comment104431581_59096959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Don't know if there's another method for counter, but it Worked with me :

```
my $element;
$counter_rec2 = 0;
$counter_rec1 = 0;

foreach $element ( @{$struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'networkInfo'}->{'recEntityInfo'} } ) {

    if (defined $element->{recEntityType} && $element->{recEntityType}==2 && $counter_rec2 == 0 ) {
        $recEntityCode2=$element->{recEntityCode};
        $counter_rec2 = $counter_rec2 +1;
        print "recEntityCode: $recEntityCode2\n";
    }

    if (defined $element->{recEntityType} && $element->{recEntityType}==1 && $counter_rec1 == 0 ) {
        $counter_rec1 = $counter_rec1 +1;
        $recEntityCode1=$element->{recEntityCode};
        print "recEntityCode: $recEntityCode1\n";
    }

}

print "this is value for 2 $recEntityCode2\n";
print "this is value for 1 $recEntityCode1\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there're many solutions depending on what you exactly have and what you exactly want (TIMTOWTDI, you know). Do you know an exact number of entity types? Are you sure there's at least one array element for each of those entities?

The following code is rather dirty and proof-of-concept just to give you an idea, and it answers the literal question as it was asked (I assume your input hash is referenced as `$r`):

```perl
no strict;
no warnings;
use List::Util qw(first);

for my $type (1, 2) {
    ${qq|recEntityCode_$type|} = (first { $_->{recEntityType} == $type } $r->{recEntityInfo}->@*)->{recEntityCode};
}

print $recEntityCode_1 . "\n";
print $recEntityCode_2 . "\n";
```

For sure, I wouldn't use it. Much better way is to create a hash to store your results and not to declare separate variables for each of them:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(first);

my %recEntityCodes;

for my $type (1, 2) {
    $recEntityCodes{$type} = (first { $_->{recEntityType} == $type } $r->{recEntityInfo}->@*)->{recEntityCode};
}

print $recEntityCodes{1} . "\n";
print $recEntityCodes{2} . "\n";
```

Easy to see it is not optimal either, as we're walking the array from the start for each type (again, just to demonstrate one of possible solutions).

The simpliest solution I can invent out of my head is the following:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %recEntityCodes;

$recEntityCodes{$_->{recEntityType}} //= $_->{recEntityCode} for $r->{recEntityInfo}->@*;

print $recEntityCodes{1} . "\n";
print $recEntityCodes{2} . "\n";
```

Here we walk an array just once, but, on the other hand, we always walk the whole array.

Which one is the best is up to you. If you array is short enough you usually don't care and just take variant 3 as shortest code. If the array is large, either of variants 2 or 3 may be profitable depending on array properties. If the array is really huge, it worth optimizing further.